# Java swing. How to change color intensity from black to white?

Tags: java, swing, colors, rgb, grayscale

I don't see  the how to change color only from black to white. Grayscale.

My example. I have values that goes from 0 to 100.

Their representation is like this:

0 - Black

100 - White

I am painting JComponent and whenever I have to change color I have to call

```
g.setColor(Color);
```

But how to tell it to change color only from Black to White, depending of my number (the larger the number, color is whiter)?
How to manipulate over RGB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, of course, no color change from black to white, per se, except through gradually lighter shades of gray.

So, just use equal values of RGB, treating 0 - 100 as a percentage of 255.

For example, 50% is RGB of 128,128,128 (though depending on rounding you might arrive at 127,127,127).

The expression for going from a percentage value to a 0-255 is:

```
rgb=(pct*255)/100;
```

Answer (score 4):

The Color API has HSB values which you may find easier to use.

You can also use the [HSL Colors](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/). Check out the "luminance" tab when you start with a black or white color.

Comment: The question specifically asked "How to manipulate over RGB?".

Comment: @pouncep: HSB & HSL are useful alternatives to consider. In HSB for example, setting h=0, s=0 and b=0..255 produces 256 equally spaced grays. See also  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/uiswing/components/ex6/ColorChooserDemo.jnlp

Comment: The basic question was about gray scale. Many times people don't know alternatives. I try to provide different approaches and then people can choose the approach they understand. For many people the "concept" of changing the brightness (in HSB) or the luminosity (in HSL) makes more sense then changing all three RGB values.

Comment: +1: I agree with camkickr, and can immediately see some places where this can help me with some of my code.  I confess to having been locked in an RGB mind-set for so long I don't often consider HSB and HSL alternatives.

Comment: In fact, I just wrote some shade-changing code for colors where I bet HSB or HSL will work much better.  Adding a to-do item to look into this now.

Answer (score -2):

As long as values are equal in rgb you have a grey.

so

```
g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0);
```

is white.

```
g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255);
```

is black

```
g.setColor(new Color(128,128,128);
```

is an equal blend of white and black.